# Michael Hartl Rails Tutorial - Listing 11.36 (AJAX Unfollow) Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In [listing 11.36](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) of Michael Hartl's superb tutorial, changes the unfollow form to use AJAX, but I keep getting the following error when I click on the "Unfollow" button:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
```

The form, however, does work. If I click "Unfollow" I unfollow the currently displayed user. So it seems that @user in the form declaration is valid when the form is submitted:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user),
         html: { method: :delete },
         remote: true) do |f| %>
```

but perhaps it's no longer available when the "Follow" form tries to load?

I've tried at length to track this down but I can't figure it out, and I haven't seen anyone else post the same issue.

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: I answered my own question. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agh ... Dumb error.

I had copied the code for app/views/relationships/create.js.erb into  app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb as well. Copy-and-paste error.

Sorry for the false alarm. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but if the async call worked and the following user reference is sucessfully deleted from the database the referenced @user is pointing to nil cause this reference has just been deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have following action defined in your Relationships controller?

```
def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, I had that code in my Relationships controller. See my response above. Thanks for your response.